# If $T:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}^2$ a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}^2$ is the function given as $T\begin{pmatrix}x+\imath y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x-\imath y\\x+\imath y\end{pmatrix}$  where $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2\in \mathbb{C}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$
is a linear transfomation?

I think is not a linear transfomation

$T(\vec{v}_1+\vec{v}_2)= \begin{pmatrix}(x_{1}+x_{2})-\imath (y_1+y_2)\\(x_{1}+x_{2})+\imath (y_1+y_2)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1-\imath y_1\\x_1+\imath y_1\end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix}x_2-\imath y_2\\x_2+\imath y_2\end{pmatrix} = T(\vec{v}_1) + T(\vec{v}_2) $

but $T(\lambda\vec{v}) \neq \lambda T(\vec{v})$ (this is where I'm not secure if I'm right or not)

Comment: It is a linear transformation when the two spaces are considered real vector spaces, but not when considered as complex vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove it is not a linear transformation, you need to find a value of $\lambda$ where $T(\lambda \vec v)\neq\lambda T(\vec v)$.

As Said in the comment, if $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, it works. So, we need a value with an imaginary part.

We could use $\lambda=i$. Then
$$T(i(x+iy))=T(-y+ix)=\begin{pmatrix}-y-ix\\-y+ix\end{pmatrix}\neq i\begin{pmatrix}x-iy\\x+iy\end{pmatrix}=iT(x+iy)$$